# How can I get the name's Entry for tkinter.messagebox in this code?

Tags: python, function, tkinter, tk-toolkit, messagebox

How can I get the name's Entry for tkinter.messagebox in this code? The def.OnClick doesn't see myInput variable. Help me please, I'm newbie at Python

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter.font import names

# window settings
win = Tk()
win.geometry("250x350")
win.resizable(0,0)
win.title("Test app")

# def and other
Input1 = StringVar()
def show1():
    myLabel3 = Label(win, text="I love Python :)", font=("Montserrat", 18), highlightbackground='darkred', highlightthickness=3)
    myLabel3.place(x=30, y=130)
    myLabel4 = Label(win, text="Now, enter your name!", font=("Montserrat", 15))
    myLabel4.place(x=5, y=190)
    myInput = Entry(win, font=("Montserrat", 17), textvariable=Input1, width=100, justify=LEFT)
    myInput.place(x=0, y=240)
    Button2 = Button(win, text="Apply", font=("Montserrat"), command=onClick)
    Button2.place(x=90, y=290)
def onClick():
    tk.messagebox.showinfo("Your name", f"Your name - {myInput}")
# widgets
myLabel1 = Label(win, text="Hello World!", font=("Montserrat", 20))
myLabel2 = Label(win, text="Click this button!", font=("Montserrat", 16))
Button1 = Button(win, text="Click me pls!", font=("Montserrat"), command=show1)

# widgets settings
myLabel1.place(x=35)
myLabel2.place(x=26, y=40)
Button1.place(x=62, y=83)

win.mainloop()
```

Comment: replace `{myInput}` with `{Input1.get()}`

Comment: Please post and accept an answer, so that other users know that the question has been answered satisfactorily.

Answer (score 0):

replace {myInput} with {Input1.get()}

```
# def and other
Input1 = StringVar()
def show1():
    myInput = Entry(win, font=("Montserrat", 17), textvariable=Input1, width=100, justify=LEFT)
    myInput.place(x=0, y=240)
    Button2 = Button(win, text="Apply", font=("Montserrat"), command=onClick)
    Button2.place(x=90, y=290)
def onClick():
    tk.messagebox.showinfo("Your name", f"Your name - {Input1.get()}")

win.mainloop()
```